# Password validation pattern

Tags: html, css, angular

For password validation pattern Without white space and 6 characters I'm using constant password pattern = /[^\s]+.{6,}/;

my requirement is only 6 characters that can be anything except space

But this is not working.

```js
const passwordreg = this.registrationForm.value.passwordreg;
    const passwordpattern = /[^\s]+.{6,}/;
    
    if (passwordreg === null || passwordreg === undefined || passwordreg === '' ) {
      this.showMessagesregist = true;
      this.errorMessage = 'Please Enter Password';
      return;
    } 
    else if(!passwordpattern.test(passwordreg)){
      this.showMessagesregist = true;
      this.errorMessage = 'Password must be at least 6 characters.';
      return;
    }
```

```html
<input [type]="fieldTextType ? 'text' : 'password'" autocomplete="passwordreg"                         formControlName="passwordreg"  class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Enter Password">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the correct regex you are looking for, then:

```
/^\S{6,}$/
```

This will ensure you have minimum 6 characters without any white-space allowed.

If you want to dissallow space, but allow tab, new line and carriage return, then you use:

```
/^[^ ]{6,}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$"

This is minimum 8 characters, number lower, upper and special characters.
If you want to set upper bound and lower bound for number of characters change{minCharLength,maxCharLength}

In your case,
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{6,}$"

Comment: I can enter any character except space and it should be 6 characters. there is no mandatory to use  at least one number and includes both lower and uppercase letters and special characters, my requirement is only 6 characters that can be anything except space